# Error getting spatial reference as string in arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy, coordinate-system, xml

I am trying to get the string associated with a spatial reference to print into an xml using arcpy and xml.cElementTree.  Using the snippet:

```
...
spatial_ref = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
...
Prj = et.SubElement(spaceref, "Prj")
space = arcpy.SpatialReference(spatial_ref)
Prj.text = arcpy.SpatialReference.exportToString(space)
...
```

Using essentially the same method, I am able to get the string to print with IDLE by pointing directly to a projection (.prj) file, e.g.:

> u"GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119522E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"

but Arc returns this error when I try to run my script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "\DEFOE\Proc Storage\ORTHO\Arc Custom Tools\ImportUltracam.py", line 99, in 
>       space = arcpy.SpatialReference(spatial_ref)
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 927, in **init**
>       self._arc_object.createFromFile(item)
>   RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

Is there a way to input a spatial reference with Arc and return the string to be printed into the xml?

**Update**
Playing with IDLE, I tried with an EPSG code and was able to do exactly what I wanted:

```
>>> epsg = arcpy.SpatialReference(32618)
>>> print epsg
<geoprocessing spatial reference object object at 0x000000000C7D0710>
>>> arcpy.SpatialReference.exportToString(epsg)
u"PROJCS['WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_18N',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-75.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5120900 -9998100 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"
```

So I tried with an EPSG code in the script:

```
spatial_ref = "32618"
Prj = et.SubElement(spaceref, "Prj")
space = arcpy.SpatialReference(spatial_ref)
Prj.text = arcpy.SpatialReference.exportToString(space)
```

And I get the same error.

Comment: Here's a wild stab: Have you tried the `getOutput` method on your spatial reference string? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000n000000 ; http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000046000000 ; http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55246/cast-arcpy-result-as-an-integer-instead-arcpy-getcount-management

Comment: I'm not sure calling a spatial reference is considered a tool with an output value.  I got the error:
AttributeError: 'SpatialReference' object has no attribute 'getOutput'

Comment: I wouldn't expect assigning a unicode string to an etree object  to cause problems, but have you tried decoding to an ascii string?

Comment: I noticed that your EPSG code example is passing an integer in the IDLE repl but you're using a string in the actual script. Looking at the documentation for arcpy.SpatialReference, it looks like it expects an integer.

Comment: @Wes Done! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that would indicate why the file path version isn't working but I noticed that the EPSG code in your second script is being created/passed as a string whereas the documentation seems to expect an integer.